# Swift: How to assign a value whose type is 'AnyObject!'?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use the Google Maps pod, but I'm having an issue setting a variable that's of type AnyObject!.

Here's my code:

`mapPin.userData = venue as Venue`

It complains `Cannot assign value of type 'Venue' to type 'AnyObject!'`. How do I fix this error? P.S. Venue is just a custom type that I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AnyObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_AnyObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs9AnyObject) is the protocol to which all *classes* conform.
Therefore `Venue` must be defined as `class Venue` (and not `struct Venue`), otherwise instances of that type are not assignable to
a property of type `AnyObject`.

Comment: yep you guys are totally right. is there a way i can work around this? or is the only way to change it to a class

Comment: There is no way around it. If necessary, define a `class BoxedVenue` which has a `struct Venue` as the only property, and assign that to `userData`.